# What server-side programming language is this?

Tags: java, php, python, ruby, lua

The server is spitting out

```
array(16) { ["#theme"]=> string(5) "field" ["#weight"]=> int(0) ["#title"]=> string(16) "Syndication Info" ["#access"]=> bool(true) ["#label_display"]=> string(5) "above" ["#view_mode"]=> string(15) "_custom_display" ["#language"]=> string(3) "und" ["#field_name"]=> string(22) "field_syndication_info" ["#field_type"]=> string(9) "text_long" ["#field_translatable"]=> string(1) "0" ["#entity_type"]=> string(4) "node" ["#bundle"]=> string(7) "product" ["#object"]=> object(stdClass)#1293 (55) { ["vid"]=> string(3) "991" ["uid"]=> string(3) "196" ["title"]=> string(30)
```

onto a web page I'm trying to fix. I know this is some time of server-side language, but I'm not sure which one, so I'm assuming it's one I don't know (i.e. anything outside of C#.NET).

Comment: Looks like a PHP var_dump

Comment: Neither is it `python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of this "spit" is a PHP dump. To be sure, if you have access to the source files, see if the file extension is .php. If you don't and the website is live, try seeing if you can access the index.php of the website, or try taking a look on http://builtwith.com/

Comment: While I agree with the first part (spit), you cannot neither conclude from the file extension (there might be configurations where `.php`files are parsed as python) nor from the actual output it generates. When you `echo "Test";` with PHP or `print("Test")` with python, such a webservice will only see "Test" and nothing more.

Comment: Well, you are technically right, that is certainly possible, but unlikely the case!

Answer (score 0):

> [Can you hear me now?](https://twitter.com/Snowden/status/648890134243487744)

This is `PHP` for sure :-)